# How to access PDF file in direct input tag

Tags: php, html

How to access PDF file in direct input tag.
Auto access file instead of file select using file name and path.
i want to select file(auto) and send to convert pdf to jpg.

```
type="file"
```

I want particular file to be select like value.

```
<?php //Work in php ?> 

<input type="file" id="file-to-upload" accept="application/pdf" value="/abcd.pdf">
```

Comment: Do you want to limit the file search to similar values of abcd.pdf?

Comment: yes. not only limit, i am uploading file from other page and also storing path in database so later i can update the file i want select and perform actions.

Comment: There is no way to access the local address of selected file through a browser

Comment: need to do something i needed this

Comment: do you want to embed it?

Comment: yes. i want access perticular

Comment: Do you mean you want to specify the file name upfront via your code, for the file to be automatically selected, so that the user does not have to do anything any more? That is of course not possible in the context of a normal website ...

Comment: okay what we do now, we are developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to embed PDF to view in browser.

```
<embed src="abc_file.pdf" width="500px" height="500px" />
```

You can adjust height and width according to Your need. You can also add `type="application/pdf"` with above tag.

You can do the same using `iframe` also.

```
<iframe src="file_name.pdf" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>
```

Hope this help.
If you have any query, feel free to contact me.

Comment: for what reason, you need that for only `input` tag?

Comment: i want to select file and send to convert pdf to jpg.

Comment: `<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf"/>` then what is problem with this. it will only accept pdf files.

Comment: i want to select auto like value="file.pdf"

Comment: question looks like unclear. Please provide more information.

Comment: sure, normally i am selecting a file and uploading to convert, but i need to access auto from folder

Comment: Sorry, not possible from my side. as i questioned in comment about `embed`, this only i can provide you.